# next and previous buttons using php

Tags: php, html, slideshow

I'm reposting this question because I only got one answer that didn't work or help at all.
I'm trying to make a php slideshow and I'm almost done I just need to implement the next and back buttons which I thought were going to be easy, but apparently you can't increment indexes in php?

```
$sql = "SELECT pic_url FROM pic_info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = 0;
$dir = "http://dev2.matrix.msu.edu/~matrix.training/Holmberg_Dane/";
$source = "gallery.php";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    $pic_array = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
        $count++;
    }

    $index = 1;
    echo "<img src= ' $dir$pic_array[$index]' />";

    echo "<a href= '$dir$pic_array[$index + 1]'>next</a>";
    echo "<a href= '$dir$pic_array[$index - 1]'>back</a>";
}



$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is destined to break. Incrementing the index like that means it will only work for array items from 1 to the next to last before it runs into a key that doesn't exist. However, I can see what you are trying to do, you simply need to use concatenation, which is the period in php, and remember not to mix double and single quotes.  This should work for you.

```
echo "<img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />";
echo "<a href= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index + 1].">next</a>";
echo "<a href= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index - 1].">back</a>";
```

Comment: The next and back buttons work, but I thought my problem was going to be something that I knew how to fix. I thought the indexes would be out of range, but after I click the link there's no more next or back buttons which makes sense, but I have no idea how to move forward after that.